# In Public IaaS cloud, if my VM is given any available pCPU core, how sure am I that I get all the cores I pay for?

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization, hypervisor

I am a new comer to virtualization!

At least from what I know, in virtualization if I have a VM, the scheduler will give it any core available for processing in the physical CPU (pCPU) and it is also not advisable to permanently assign a pCPU core to a VM. In public IaaS clouds, customers select a VM with preset resources and they will certainly pay for these resources as long their VMs are active even if they are probably utilizing their resources say 20 % these resources. How sure am I that I get all the cores I pay for even when I am not using them?

Answer (score 1):

> How sure am I that I get all the cores I pay for even when I am not using them?

The thing is just the opposite: Depending on the specific virt model and instance type, you can be sure that you *don't* get the resources when you don't use them.

Providers will overcommit resources on the assumption that many customers won't have 100% utilization at all times. This is reflected in the contracts and essentially *is* what you are paying for.